# Hyper-V Manager : How to remove a bad VM

Tags: hyper-v

I tried creating a VM for Ubuntu 20.04 and it went unstable...it stays at Stopping state forever...I am not even able to delete it.
What should I do to remove this VM?

[image]

Comment: if reboot is acceptable, you should be able to remove after reboot

Answer (score 1):

Here is a powershell script that should kill the VM Process of the VMNAMEHERE virtual machine.

```perl
$VMGUID = (Get-VM "VMNAMEHERE").ID
$VMWMProc = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | ? {$_.Name -match 'VMWP' -and $_.CommandLine -match $VMGUID})
Stop-Process ($VMWMProc.ProcessId) -Force
```